# Why do I have "message": "Expected 1 bindings, saw 0" when using array_agg with knex?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js, array-agg

I'm using postgres and I try to make my request with array_agg in knex, but I have the error:

**"message": "Expected 1 bindings, saw 0"**

Does anyone know where this error may come from? And how can I fix it?

my request:

```js
knex('user')
.leftJoin('user_has_restaurant','user_has_restaurant.user_id','user.id')
.leftJoin('restaurant','user_has_restaurant.restaurant_id', 
'restaurant.id')
.select([
'user.id AS user_id',
'user.name AS user_name',
 knex.raw(
  'ARRAY_AGG(restaurant.id) as id',
  'ARRAY_AGG(restaurant.name) as name',
  'ARRAY_AGG(restaurant.description) as description',
  'ARRAY_AGG(restaurant.website) as website',
  'ARRAY_AGG(restaurant.created_at) as created_at',
  'ARRAY_AGG(restaurant.updated_at) as updated_at')
])
.groupBy('user.id')
.whereIn('user.id',`${userId}`)
```

Of course my userId is a dynamic array like [1 , 2 , 3 ... ]

Answer (score 0):

try passing it like this `.whereIn('user.id',userId)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your second parameter!
when you do whereIn - the second parameter needs to be array and not string,

Just change to .whereIn('user.id',userId)